# A web page that aggregates the results of a search on different sites

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, dynamic

My wife runs a small bookshop. Every day she is asked for a book from her customers, and every time she checks if the book is available in the shop. If not, she looks on her suppliers' web sites and checks which ones have the book. She has to open various web pages (one for each supplier) and do some steps for each site to get the answer.

It would be nice for her to have a single page from which she launches the search on each of the websites.

I suppose that the simplest idea is to write a local html page that can be sliced in some frames, one for each of the suppliers website, and then each frame contains the web page of a supplier.

Anyway I could have some more fun, and I could write a little scraper (there are no API) for each website, and then when a search is run, multiple scrapers are run and as soon as the result are received, they are shown dynamically in a table, this way:

```
SUPPLIER#1 - ISBN - TITLE - AUTHOR - PRICE - AVAILABLE PCS
SUPPLIER#2 - ISBN - TITLE - AUTHOR - PRICE - AVAILABLE PCS
SUPPLIER#1 - ISBN - TITLE - AUTHOR - PRICE - AVAILABLE PCS
```

So she has in seconds a clear and concise representation of the situation and she is able to do the right choice and make her customers happier :-)

I also would like to have some fun and try and learn something new. What would be a state-of-the-art structure that could accomplish my goal, based on the available web technologies?

Comment: Frames!?! Eeek!  That notwithstanding, check out javascript `fetch(url)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Anyway I can give it a try if I don't get nowhere with a more complex solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can host a server which would scrape realtime the configured suppliers' websites and stream the results back to your wife's browser.
You can explore NodeJs for the server side and React/redux or VueJs on client side.

Nothing cutting edge in terms of tech, but it should be fun.
I suggest you read this article: [Streaming Json Jsons](https://instantdomainsearch.com/articles/streaming-json-jsons/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't scrape them realtime: I need to do a keyword search and then get the result. It could go like this:  

 - the web page start the concurrent loading of four web pages (one for each supplier) with a certain keyword (how?)  

 - the received pages are scraped by python/beautifulsoup and the outputs in json format is injected back to a javascript program that merges and show them by using VueJs. (how this connection could be made)  


Sorry for my basic questions; maybe they're also put in the wrong way.